# multicolored line with strings linecolllection

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm using linecollection from matplotlib in order to create multi colored line similar to this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html
but instead of using x and y both float types, I was wondering if its possible to create a line where x axis would be strings lets say: x=`['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k']` . So every of those strings has a value for example `y=np.arange(10)`. So is plotting a multicolored line that connects those xy points using linecollection possible?

Comment: For sure it's possible to draw a multicolored line. Since xticklabels can be set independently of the data, I do not see the problem. Would you like to share your code such that it becomes clear what this question is about?

Comment: If you have strings you can always map them to numbers and then [set the axis labels accordingly](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html). [This example is better](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html)

Comment: @berna1111 I've managed to do this, thanks for the tips, added the code and results to the question

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept your answer, marking the question as `answered`. Interesting graphic by the way - is that games released per publisher?

Comment: Yes this is dataset of games realeased by publisher ( counting one title for one platform, thats why EA is not first on the list). You can get the whole set here: https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings/kernels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I managed to do this, the code below if you need. The data(gbpndupl) im plotting is simple Series where index column is publisher names and the other column are the numbers. I also uploaded the image of how it looks like.

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
x=np.arange(40)
y=gbpndupl.iloc[:40]
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='plasma',norm=plt.Normalize(0, 10)) 
#norm can be changed to decide how fast color changes
lc.set_linewidth(3)
lc.set_array(x)
plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))
plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))
plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
labels=list(gbpndupl.iloc[:40].index)
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical');
```

[image]