# How to use LineCollection with set of strings in segments array

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line with three different colors based on other conditions:

- I have a dataframe x_week where the column `['Year-Week']` contains a string of year and week in the form `'%Y-w%U'`
- The column `x_week['#ops']` are float numbers
- The limits where I want to change color of the line are stored in a dictionary named `week` that also contains strings in the format `'%Y-w%U'`

I am using `LineCollection`, the problem is that it requieres that the string element of the array segment being float, I have already tried `date2num` but I want to mantain the format `'%Y-w%U'` for the x-axis

(I already look into here [multicolored line with strings linecolllection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836100/multicolored-line-with-strings-linecolllection) )

```
 x = x_week['Year-Week']
    y = x_week['ops']
    
    # select how to color
    color = []
    
    for i in range(3):
        
        color.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
        
    cmap = ListedColormap(color)
    norm = BoundaryNorm([min(x_week['Year-Week']),week[1],week[2],week[3],max(x_week['Year-Week'])], cmap.N)
    
    points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
    
    # make line collection
    lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap = cmap, norm = norm)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-279-6f4c3a13d43e> in <module>
     18 
     19 # make line collection
---> 20 lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap = cmap, norm = norm)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in __init__(self, segments, linewidths, colors, antialiaseds, linestyles, offsets, transOffset, norm, cmap, pickradius, zorder, facecolors, **kwargs)
   1331             **kwargs)
   1332 
-> 1333         self.set_segments(segments)
   1334 
   1335     def set_segments(self, segments):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in set_segments(self, segments)
   1340         for seg in segments:
   1341             if not isinstance(seg, np.ma.MaskedArray):
-> 1342                 seg = np.asarray(seg, float)
   1343             _segments.append(seg)
   1344 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-w27'
```

Comment: can you "map" the date-week# to an integer and then use the integer to map the color? you can still keep the desired format for the xaxis

Comment: @AlexS1 I got this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019-w27', I had to add the w because if not I would need to add a day and I don't have it